# How to classify graph symmetry group with an algorithm?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, permutations, algorithms, automorphism-group

I'm trying to develop (or if possible find an implementation of) an algorithm to classify the symmetry group of an undirected graph.

Consider an undirected graph $G = \{N, E\}$, where $N = \{n_i\}$ - nodes and $E = \{(n_i, n_j)\}$ - edges. [Nauty](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) one of the popular tools people use to work with graph symmetries can be used to obtain generators of the symmetry group. Let's call the symmetry (automorphism) group $A(G)$ and it's generators $a_1...a_l$. I want to consider a simple graph, that is, the graph in which the orbit of $A(G)$ is all the nodes of $G$ (any graph can be factorized in the independent graphs, some of which may have only one node, that have this property). The question is how can I algorithmically classify $A(G)$ i.e. how can I tell that it's $D_4$ or $C_{15}$ or $S_3$ or whatever else? My only idea is to come up with the logic similar to what people do with point groups in crystals, like [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Symmetry_(Vallance)/01%3A_Chapters/1.03%3A_Symmetry_Classification_of_Molecules-_Point_Groups), but I wonder if there is an easier way.

I may not be formulating this clearly, so I would be happy to correct it in accordance to your corrections. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what the following sentences mean: "all the nodes of the graph are touched by at least one permutation of the symmetry group",  " entire graph is symmetric", "any graph can be broken down into parts that have this property"? I think your question will be easier to understand if you use proper well-defined mathematical language.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are referring to. Do you mean the set of all automorphisms of a given graph when you are talking about symmetry group?

Comment: @verret Thank you for the question. Corrected the question a little bit. Is this clearer? What I meant is that all nodes of the graph are an orbit of the automorphism group. Any graph can be decomposed into induced subgraphs that have this property, some of which will obviously have only one node

Comment: @DavidScholz yes. Corrected that. Thank you for the correction

Comment: Ok, this is a little better. First, such graphs are usually called vertex-transitive graphs, and are very well-studied. (For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph) They are still too wide a class to admit a complete classification in any meaningful way. If you just want an algorithm to find the automorphism group, you already know about Nauty, so what is missing?

Comment: @verret so, I can find an automorphism group with nauty, but what I want is to classify it algorithmically. I need to run this algorithm on the big set of graphs and I want to see if the class of an automorphism group is correlated with some other information I have about these graphs. Does this make sense?

Comment: Just to give a random recent example, this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.07183 appeared on the arxiv about a week ago. Among other things, they computed all the vertex-transitive graphs of order 48 (with 48 nodes). There are 1538868366, and many different automorphisms groups. So there is no hope of getting a nice classification like in the case of crystals.

Comment: Automorphisms groups of vertex-transitive graphs are a very rich class, and cannot be classified in the same way as symmetry groups of molecules (finite subgroups of $SO(3)$) can. The best you can hope for in that direction is to put them in very wide categories, such as "does it contain a regular subgroup (so the graph is Cayley)?", "is it regular itself?", "is it some kind of nice product?", etc.

Comment: I think it's probably true in general, but my experience with problems like this is that in practice most of the graphs that are based on the real data have a fairly simple structure. That is, most of them would be dihedral or cyclic or cyclic with mirror. Do you have any thoughts on how I can check for these three types of groups? Or maybe how I can check if it has a subgroup that is one of them?

Comment: Most graphs that are based on real data are not vertex-transitive. In fact, I would expect most graphs based on "real data" to have trivial automorphism group. 
Now, if you obtain these vertex-transitive graphs as "factors" from bigger non-vertex-transitive graphs (I'm not sure what factorisation you have in mind exactly), I would expect them to generally be fairly small. So the most common types of automorphism groups would $S_n$ and $D_n$. (A simple undirected vertex-transitive graph actually cannot have a cyclic automorphism group, except for $C_2$.)

Comment: If you have the generators given by nauty, you can simply plug those in into a system for dealing with groups, such as magma and GAP, and test for isomorphism with whichever groups you like. For example, go to http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ and try the following program
G:=Sym(4);
g:=G!(1,2,3,4);
h:=G!(1,3);
IsIsomorphic(sub<G|g,h>,DihedralGroup(4));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120064/discussion-between-ian-and-verret).

Comment: We came to a tentative solution. Will share if I'll make this work. Meanwhile, would be happy to take any other ideas.

Comment: @verret Actually, in a sense, the arXiv article that you refer to does classify the automorphism groups of the vertex-transitive graphs of degree $48$. They are all conjugate in the symmetric group to one of $195,826,352$ transitive groups of degree $48$. OK, perhaps that cannot be described as a nice classification :(

Comment: I found a tool that has an interface to Magma and GAP from Python and it's called [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/). Going to install and play with it. To be continued...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.07821.pdf) in which I discuss solution to this problem in section VII.

There are two steps to this problem:
(1) decompose the automorphism group into subgroups to be classified and
(2) classify each subgroup.

I was able to solve problem 1 by using the approach proposed by [MacArthur et. al.](https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/54120/1/symmetry.pdf). Namely, I used geometric decomposition (see the paper for more details) of the automorphism group, which factorizes the symmetry group into normal subgroups acting on the different parts of the graph.

Problem 2 was solved after a very helpful discussion with [@verret](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/191246/verret). Proposed approach is computational and is based on a very simple idea: take a subgroup and check if it is isomorphic to any of the traditional symmetry groups. In my case I compared them with $S_n$, $D_n$, $C_n$ and $A_n$, for $n$ between 1 and the number of nodes.

Implementation of the solution to both problems (1) and (2) and a little more can be found at my [GitHub](https://github.com/makselab/PseudoBalancedColoring).